# In nginx, how to allow any string as an http method?

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy server.

My application servers behind it accept custom extension methods for requests.
For example, "MYMETHOD".

However the nginx default configuration seems to only accept non-extension methods, such as HEAD, GET, POST, etc, and returns a default nginx 400 response for requests that did not have a non-extension method, instead of proxying those requests to my app servers.

How can I make nginx accept and proxy any http requests regardless of their method?

I do not want to whitelist specific methods, because this would require me to change the nginx configuration every time I need to support a new method in my app servers, and I do not want those to be tightly coupled.

[edit]

The solution has to work for official supported nginx distributions, either on nginx.com or popular linux distributions (debian, centos, etc).

Obviously I can just alter the nginx source code and make it pass along any methods, but if I'm altering the source code and recompiling it's no longer nginx but rather a fork of it.

Comment: There's an open issue on nginx regarding this: https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/issues/602

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Looks like it had no progress since 2016. Frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ngx_http_allow_methods_module](https://github.com/pschultz/ngx_http_allow_methods_module) for allowing custom HTTP methods. This module allows arbitrary HTTP methods to be passed to a backend application.

Example:

```
http {
    server {

        location /api/ {
            allow_methods ".*";
        }

    }
}
```

**Directive**

```
allow_methods "^(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE|PATCH|LINK|COPY)$";
```

This directive describes HTTP methods that should be passed along. The pattern is case-sensitive (as per RFC 2616). If it is absent, the default rules of Nginx apply. You should use this directive only in the locations that you really need it in.

Comment: I cannot accept this answer because it requires recompilation of nginx. I need a solution that works for official supported nginx distributions. Also, the author of this module points out it's a hacky solution that is prone to errors, as it tricks nginx to think each request is a GET request, which can conflict with other modules. This is not suitable for my needs.

Comment: I'd argue that if you take an open source project, modify it to your needs, it still is the Nginx code base that you modified, and if you push your changes to the repository upstream, it can be absorbed within the project and become part of Nginx code base, hence, if you modify it to your needs and your changes are accepted and committed upstream, you can still consider it Nginx, now with your changes.

Comment: I completely agree with this open source philosophy and it's probably what I'll end up doing, but unfortunately this doesn't work for my original needs that led me to post this question.