# Trying to have a contact form on my website email me using HTML

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to add a contact form on my website using a simple bit of php code. I'm sure I'm overlooking something small, any help would be appreciated!

I fear it may be that I am using div for the fields and not defining them in the form but am honestly not sure.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.8s" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
    <form action="process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" class="single-form quate-form wow fadeInUp" data-toggle="validator">
        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <input name="name" class="contact-name form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <input name="name" class="contact-email form-control" id="L_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input name="name" class="contact-subject form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <textarea class="contact-message" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- Submit Button -->
            <div class="btn-form col-sm-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-block" id="form-submit">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
     
    $EmailTo = "email@email.com";
    $Subject = "Portfolio CV/Resume";
     
    // prepare email body text
    
    $Body .= "Name: ";
    $Body .= $name;
    $Body .= "\n"; 
     
    $Body .= "Email: ";
    $Body .= $email;
    $Body .= "\n";
     
    $Body .= "Message: ";
    $Body .= $message;
    $Body .= "\n";
     
    
    // send email
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);
     
    // redirect to success page
    if ($success){
       echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "invalid";
    } 
?>
```

**EDIT:** I changed name="name" and am getting 405 error. I am using Ubunut with Nginx if that helps

Comment: `name="name"` is an issue.  Do you get `success` or `invalid`? `$_POST["name"]` and others won't exist only `name` index will, and everyone will be overwritten. PHP error reporting should throw a notice about the undefined indexes.

Comment: You have 3 `name="name"` attributes. the names are generally the same as what the `id=` attribute values contain. Do a `var_dump($_POST);` to see what you get after submit.

Comment: @PaulT. I added var_dump($_POST); and still get a 405 POST error. I also changed the `name="name" ` to match the `id=` section. If I get nginx to server static pages it spits out my PHP code on the website once submitted

Comment: The textarea does not have a `name` attribute. That likely will not solve the issue, but another thing noted.

Comment: Thank you @PaulT. sadly still getting a 405 post error

Comment: The 405 error means that something, I'm assuming the `post`, is possibly not allowed? See if some of the items [mentioned here](https://kinsta.com/blog/405-method-not-allowed-error/) may help, or possibly the [see also links here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)  The first link is one from Mozilla's list.

Comment: Thank you again @PaulT. - I fear it may be an issue with nginx not serving static pages from post but when I change it to allow following some other stack overflow post all it does is spit out all the PHP code on the website. I'm at a loss. Sorry to keep bothering you!

Comment: See if [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59409322/7644018) may help. I'm relative new to nginx myself.

Comment: Still no joy :/ nginx likes to give me trouble every step of the way, haha. Thank you so much for your time, I'm not sure what to do at this point. Might just rework the entire contact form as my current solution isn't working. Thank you again, stay safe @PaulT.

Comment: You probably did, but if you made changes, ensure to save and restart nginx.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, if you have same issue let me know please ---

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.8s" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
    <form action="process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" class="single-form quate-form wow fadeInUp" data-toggle="validator">
        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <input name="name" class="contact-name form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <input name="last_name" class="contact-email form-control" id="L_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input name="email" class="contact-subject form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <textarea name="message" class="contact-message" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- Submit Button -->
            <div class="btn-form col-sm-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-block" id="form-submit">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

process.php

<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
     
    $EmailTo = "email@email.com";
    $Subject = "Portfolio CV/Resume";
     
    // prepare email body text
    
    $Body .= "Name: ";
    $Body .= $name;
    $Body .= "\n"; 
     
    $Body .= "Email: ";
    $Body .= $email;
    $Body .= "\n";
     
    $Body .= "Message: ";
    $Body .= $message;
    $Body .= "\n";

    
    // send email
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);
     
    // redirect to success page
    if ($success){
       echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "invalid";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: I'm still getting `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405` - I'm thinking it has to do with Nginx not wanting to serve a static page after a POST request.